# p:selectOneRadio with required="true", if you submit not selected, does not turn its p:selectOneRadio to red

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, radio-button

I have this `p:selectOneRadio`:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneRadio 
    value="#{bean.val}"
    id="val"
    layout="custom"
    required="true"
>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="B" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

and two `p:radioButton`s. If I submit the form ***without*** selecting any radio, the validation stops the submit, ***but*** `p:radioButton`s does ***NOT*** turn to red.

Indeed I inspected with the dev tools of the browser, and the radios has ***NO*** `ui-state-error` class.

It seems it's an error due to the old version of PrimeFaces I use. Can't I select the radio with a custom validator from `UIComponent` and set the class manually?

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: PF version? Do you use any theme? If you inspect that widget, did it gets the `ui-state-error` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In the submit button put:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { Util.checkCustomRadios(containersSel, endOfRadioNames); }, 350);"
```

This is `Util.checkCustomRadios()`:

```js
Util.checkCustomRadios = function (containersSelector, radioName) {
    "use strict";
    
    var errorClass = "ui-state-error";
    
    var $containers = $(containersSelector);
    var $container;
    var $radios;
    var radio;
    var checked;
    var $radioWrapper;
    var j;
    
    for (var i=0; i<$containers.length; i++) {
        $container = $containers.eq(i);
        $radios = $container.find('[name$="' + radioName + '"]:radio');
    
        if (! $radios.length) {
            continue;
        }
    
        checked = false;
    
        for (j=0; j<$radios.length; j++) {
            radio = $radios[j];
            if (radio.checked) {
                checked = true;
            }
        }
    
        $radioWrapper = $container.find('.ui-radiobutton-box');
        
        if (checked) {
            $radioWrapper.removeClass(errorClass);
        }
        else {
            $radioWrapper.addClass(errorClass);
        }
    }
};
```

`containersSel` could be the id of a single container or a selector of multiple containers, like `#mytable tr`.

`endOfRadioNames` is the last part of the name of the radios, before a colon.

Adjust the setTimeout value as you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed in PrimeFaces 6.2.  See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2464

OP is using PF 3.4 a 9 year old version.

Comment: I can't update. Can't I create a custom validator and get the radios from `UIComponent`?

Comment: Looking at the commit, you would need a custom renderer.